# Multiple instances of APC cache when refreshing apc.php

Tags: alternative-php-cache

Hope you guys can provide some info on an issue I'm seeing.

I'm running a Centos server with mod_fcgi and APC cache. APC cache is running, but when refreshing the apc.php, I see what look like different caches. The uptime and cache sizes for them are different. All of them show decent hit rates (over 90%) and low fragmentation.

Is this kind of behavior normal? Should I be worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCGI workers do not share an APC cache - each has its own.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57825

Using the PHP-FPM manager or a shared cache like memcached is the way to go.